# Is there an easy way to calculate $\sum_{n=0}^{20} \frac{\sin(n\pi /40)}{2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

We can calculate the partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^{20} \frac{\sin(n\pi /40)}{2^n}$ directly, but for large value of n, is there an easy way to calculate a series of this type?

Comment: Write $\sin{(n \pi/40)}$ as the imaginary part of $e^{i n \pi/40}$.  The result will be the imaginary part of a geometric series.

Comment: Notice that $f(x):=2^{-x}\cdot \sin(\displaystyle {x\pi\over 40})\to 0(x\to +\infty,)$ then we can use $\displaystyle\int_{n}^m f(x)dx$ to approximate $\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^m f(i)$ when $n,m$ are large integers. Hope this can help.

Comment: See also : $$\#76$$ of  https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{r=a}^b\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^n}=$$  imaginary part of

$$\sum_{r=a}^b\dfrac{e^{inx}}{2^n}=\sum_{r=a}^b\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}}2\right)^n$$ which is a finite Geometric Series

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi

Comment: oh wait, but i end up with $Im(\sum_{n=0}^{20} {\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2}}^n$. And the partial sum of this geometric series is $\frac{2^{21}-{e^{i\theta}}^{21}}{2^{21}-2^{21}e^{i\theta}}$ . But in my question $\theta=\frac{\pi}{40}$, to calculate $e^{i\theta}$, i have to calculate $\cos(\frac{\pi}{40})$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{40})$ . The problem becomes what are the values of the trig functions at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{40}$.....

Comment: @bbw, We can safely keep $$\cos\dfrac{\pi}{40}$$ or $$\sin\dfrac{\pi}{40}$$ in the answer. All we need to ensure is there should not be any $i$ in the final answer