# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have some problems when calculating the sum of this infinite series:
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{2^n}
$$
I've checked the convergence and found that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{2^n}$ converges (absolutely).

The answer is: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{2^n}= \frac{2cos1−1}{5−4cos1}$.

Comment: Hint: Compute $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{in}}{2^n}$$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601940/is-there-an-easy-way-to-calculate-sum-n-020-frac-sinn-pi-402n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sum is the real part of the geometric series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in}}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{e^i}2\right)^n=\frac{e^i}{2-e^i}=\frac{e^i(2-e^{-i})}{(2-e^i)(2-e^{-i})}
=\frac{2e^i-1}{5-4\cos 1}.$$