# Pure imaginary numbers : $ ( j^{2n} - j^n ) \in i\Bbb R $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Considering the complex number $j$ such that $$ j = \frac{-1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt3}{2} $$
Prove that $ \forall n \in \Bbb Z : $
$$ ( j^{2n} - j^n ) \in i\Bbb R $$

( $i\Bbb R$ being the set of pure imaginary numbers)

Comment: @Useless I considered $ u = j^{2n} - j^n $ and tried to prove that its complex conjugate was equal to $-u$ but that was to no avail

Comment: Why the upvotes? This is pure do-my-hwk-for-me-asap stuff.

Comment: Shouldn't I upvote the answers that were helpful ? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You should first and foremost start posting questions with context. That the present question received 4 upvotes signals a serious misunderstanding of the purpose of this site.

Comment: Sure. I'll keep that in mind if I post any new question. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observing that $$j^2=\left(\frac{-1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^2=-\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\overline{j}$$

then since $\Im(z) =\frac{1}{2i}(z-\overline{z})$ we obviously get  $$j^{2n}-j^n =\bar{j}^{n}-j^n =\overline{j^n} - j^n = \color{blue}{-2i\Im(j^n) \in i\Bbb R} $$

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up proving it

Comment: @Abbkey  Why did you not edit your answer here it could be helpful

Comment: I added your answer since it's similar to mine and would save me a lot of typing time, if you don't mind of course

Comment: @Abbkey Also don't forget to put a green-checkmark (see it the right to the answers) on your favored answer it is important for the visitors and reader of your post and to the incoming users of MSE

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Note that using Euler's formula, we can write $$ j = \cos \frac{2\pi}3 + i\sin \frac{2\pi}3 = e^{\dfrac{2\pi i} 3}$$ which is a complex root of unity.

Comment: @Abbkey Even without Euler's, you may notice that $j$ is a complex root of unity, so: $$j^2 = \bar j$$ the conjugate of $j$. Thus, in a few steps we can easily show that $$j^{2n}-j^n = \bar j^n - j^n \in i\mathbb R$$

Comment: I am not sure whether your $\overline j^n-j^n$ was meant to represent $\left(\bar j\right)^n-j^n$ or $\overline {\left(j^n\right)}-j^n$ - they are of course the same thing, though the second is more obviously purely imaginary

Comment: @Rohan that definitely helps. Thank you

Comment: Why the downvote on mine and @Lab's answers?

Comment: @Downvoter: I see you have downvoted my answers in a serial fashion. I don't care about it and may God judge you.

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding here. I clicked on the arrow pointing up, because I intuitively though that that was how you upvote the answers. I don't see why I would downvote since you're trying to help me. Maybe there something wrong with the app but again I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1):

$$j=e^{2\pi i/3}$$

$$j^m=e^{2\pi i m/3}=\cos\dfrac{2m\pi }3+i\sin\dfrac{2m\pi }3$$ using [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos(\varphi) +i*\sin(\varphi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi)

Now the real part $j^{2n}-j^n$

$$=\cos\dfrac{4n\pi }3-\cos\dfrac{2n\pi}3$$ $$=-2\sin2n\pi\sin\dfrac{2n\pi}3=?$$

Comment: Can u suggest another way to proving it since i'm not allowed to use Euler's formula, we haven't studied that just yet.