# Solving $\sin(z)=0$ for complex numbers $z$ by using Euler's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Using Euler's formula prove the following:
>   $$\sin(z)=0\Leftrightarrow z=\pi k\text{ for } k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried using Euler's formula?

Comment: Can we use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi ?

Comment: You could start by applying Euler's formula, but hey, that's just me.

Comment: The key for that task is to prove $\sin(z)=\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$. You see now, that all the roots of $\sin(z)$ are the roots of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: A good place to start is the definition of $\sin(z)$ when $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: Any Question that asks about "if and only if" can be started by looking at the two directions separately and asking if one is easy or easier than the other.  In this case you should notice that one of the directions is a very familiar statement about trigonometry for *real numbers*.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Note that the [sine with complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Sine_with_a_complex_argument) is defined as
$$\sin(z):=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\frac{e^{i(x+iy)}-e^{-i(x+iy)}}{2i}=
\frac{e^{-y}e^{ix}-e^{y}e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
where $z=x+iy$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by using [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos(\varphi) +i\sin(\varphi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi)
we get
$$\sin(z)=0\Leftrightarrow e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-e^{y}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x)) \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\sin(x)(e^y+e^{-y})=0 \\
\cos(x)(e^y-e^{-y})=0
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: We can continue with $z$ as well $$e^{iz}=e^{-iz}?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Usually Euler's formula is stated as $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ for real $x$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Have you noticed "This complex exponential function is sometimes denoted cis x ("cosine plus i sine"). The formula is still valid if x is a complex number,"  there? See also: https://brilliant.org/wiki/eulers-formula/.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, I am aware of that...

Comment: I don't know how to start the proof. I tried assuming z=(pi)k or sin(z)=0 but the equations I get don't make any sense or do not help.

Comment: @JoannaM Follow my hint, try again and show your efforts

Answer (score 2):

It depends on want you want to prove and how you define things... 
A way to see this question is to ask if
$$ \forall z\in \mathbb{C}, \quad \sin(z)=0 \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad  z=\pi k , \quad k\in \mathbb{z}$$ 
knowing that the same statement is true over $\mathbb{R}$... With $z=x+iy$
\begin{align*}
 \sin(z):= \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} =0 &\qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad e^{iz}=e^{-iz} \\
&\qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad e^{ix}e^{-y}=e^{-ix}e^{y}
\end{align*}
1) 
$e^{ix}e^{-y}=e^{-ix}e^{y} \Rightarrow |e^{ix}e^{-y}|=|e^{-ix}e^{y}| \Rightarrow e^{-y}=e^{y} \Rightarrow y=0$, since $t\mapsto e^t$ is strictly increasing.

2)With $y=0$,
\begin{align*}
e^{ix}e^{-y}=e^{-ix}e^{y} &\quad \Rightarrow \quad e^{ix} =e^{-ix} \\
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad \cos(x)+i\sin(x) =\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x) \\
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad \cos(x)+i\sin(x) =\cos(x)-i\sin(-x) \\
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad  \sin(x) =0 \\
&\quad \Rightarrow \quad  x=k\pi, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{align*}
So $z=k\pi+i*0=k\pi$, the converse being obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Euler's formula says that the complex exponential $e^{iz}$ can be expressed as a sum of sinusoidals:
$$e^{iz}=cos(z) + i\ sin(z)$$. Does that help?