# Solving the following equation with imaginary roots

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Okay so firstly I would like to put the question in front of you.

> Solve: $^8C_0x^8 + ^8C_2x^6 + ^8C_4x^4 + ^8C_6x^2 + 1 = 0 $

Now it is evident that the equation will only have complex roots.

I wrote the binomial expansions for $ (1+x) ^8 $ and $(1-x)^8$ and added them. After doing some simplification, I am left with this equation:

$$ (1+x)^8 + (1-x)^8 = 0 $$

I cannot proceed further.

Now I believe that I would need to use the De Moivre theorem to solve the equation, but I am not sure how to apply it in this case . Am I doing it right or is there a different way of solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^8=-1=e^{i\pi(2n+1)}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=e^{i\pi(2n+1)/8}$ where $0\le n\le7$

Now use [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/)  and [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos(\varphi) +i\sin(\varphi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi)

Comment: @ManishKundu, $$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x,$$  $$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin x,$$

Comment: Ah, fine. So that would further simplify the result?