# What is $[\cos(\pi/12)+i\sin(\pi/12)]^{16}+[\cos(\pi/12)-i\sin(\pi/12)]^{16}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

What is $[\cos(\pi/12)+i\sin(\pi/12)]^{16}+[\cos(\pi/12)-i\sin(\pi/12)]^{16}$?

I can use De Moivre's formula for the left part:

$[\cos(\pi/12)+i\sin(\pi/12)]^{16} = \cos(4\pi/3) + i\sin(4\pi/3) = -\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} + \dfrac{i}{2}$

but I'm stuck at the right part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi

Comment: By the way, you're getting the cosine and sine wrong values in the last part of your computation. It should be $-\frac12 - \frac{\sqrt3}2i$.

Comment: `I can use De Moivre's formula for the left part` Call that $z$, then the right part is just $\bar z$, so their sum is $z + \bar z = 2 \operatorname{Re}(z)$. But you need to fix the left part, first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\cos(\pi/12)-i\sin(\pi/12)=\cos(-\pi/12)+i\sin(-\pi/12)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(\cos y-i\sin y)^n=\dfrac1{(\cos y+i\sin y)^n}=\dfrac1{\cos(ny)+i\sin(ny)}=\cos(ny)-i\sin(ny)$$

as $(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos x-i\sin x)=1$

Answer (score 2):

$(\cos y-i\sin y)^n=(\cos(-y)+i\sin(-y))^n=\cos(n(-y))+i\sin(n(-y))=\cos(ny)-i\sin(ny)$

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler with the exponential notation:
\begin{align} 
(\cos\pi/12+i\sin\pi/12) ^{16}&+(\cos\pi/12-i\sin\pi/12 )^{16}\\&=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{4i\pi}3}+\mathrm e^{\tfrac{-4i\pi}3}=2\cos\frac{4\pi}3=2\cdot\frac12 
\end{align}

Comment: @dxiv: Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!