# Alternating series of powers of Cosine-squared

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, roots-of-unity, trigonometric-series

I am looking for a nice(er) proof of the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k \cos^{2j}\frac{\pi k}{2n} = -\frac{1}{2}, ~ 0<j<n,~j,n\in \mathbb{Z}^+.$$
I have been able to prove it using the following strategy. Express the cosine in terms of the complex exponential, obtaining the summand $(-1)^k\left(1/2+e^{i\pi k/n}/4+e^{-i\pi k/n}/4\right)^j$. Use the trinomial expansion to expand the bracket, then sum over $k$ which is now a geometric series. In particular, I find
$$-\sum_{p+q\leq j} {j\choose p~q} \frac{1}{2^{j-p-q}}\frac{1}{4^p}\frac{1}{4^q}
\frac{(-1)^{n+p-q}+e^{i(p-q)\pi/n}}{1+e^{i(p-q)\pi/n}}=-\sum_{p+q\leq j} {j\choose p~q} \frac{1}{2^{j-p-q}}\frac{1}{4^p}\frac{1}{4^q}\times\begin{cases}1, ~ n+p-q=\text{even}\\0, ~ n+p-q=\text{odd}\end{cases},$$
where the odd case follows as the result would be imaginary. The trinomial then reconstitutes to $$-(1/2+1/4+1/4)^j/2 \pm (1/2-1/4-1/4)^j/2=-1/2,$$ where the choice of sign depends on the parity of $n$.

Is there some deeper interpretation of this identity, and/or a slicker way to prove it? There is some clear overlap with [Sum of Fourth Powers of cosine series has closed form solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224195/sum-of-fourth-powers-of-cosine-series-has-closed-form-solution), epecially the answer given there by [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici).

Comment: For what it's worth, I spent several hours looking for a Real Analysis (only) approach, and came up empty.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a series of simplifications, to reduce to sums-of-roots-of-unity. First of all, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k\cos^{2j}\frac{\pi k}{2n}=S\implies\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^k\cos^{2j}\frac{\pi k}{2n}=2S+1$$ (this is $\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}a_k$ with $a_k=a_{2n-k}$, $a_n=0$ and $a_0=1$). Next, to get rid of $(-1)^k$, use $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^k a_k=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{2k}-\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}a_k;$$ thus, $2S+1=2S_{n,j}-S_{2n,j}$ where $S_{n,j}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^{2j}(k\pi/n)$.

Now introduce the $n$-th root of unity $\omega=\exp(2i\pi/n)$. By the binomial formula, $$2^{2j}S_{n,j}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{-kj}(1+\omega^k)^{2j}=\sum_{r=0}^{2j}\binom{2j}{r}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{k(r-j)}.$$ The inner sum is $0$ unless $n\mid(r-j)$. If $0<j<n$, the latter holds if and only if $r=j$.

Finally, we get $S_{n,j}=\frac{n}{2^{2j}}\binom{2j}{j}$ for $0<j<n$, and $2S+1=0$, hence $S=-1/2$.