# If $S(n)=i^n + i^{-n}$ n is a positive integer, then the total number of distinct values of $S(n)$ are

Tags: complex-numbers

I wrote it in the form
$$S(n)=\frac{i^{2n}+1}{i^n}$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{i^n}$$

If n is odd, then the value will be zero.

If n is even then it will become 
$$\frac{2}{-1}$$

So I can find only 2 distinct values of $S(n)$ but the answer says there are 3. What is the third value?

Comment: What if $n=4$?${}$

Comment: Okay, didn’t think of that. Multiples of 4 will give the answer as 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- $i^n=i,-1,-i,1,\dots$
- $i^{-n}=-i,-1,i,1,\dots$

and therefore

- $S(1)=i^{1} + i^{-1}=i-i=0$
- $S(2)=i^{2} + i^{-2}=-1-1=-2$
- $S(3)=i^{3} + i^{-3}=-i+i=0$
- $S(4)=i^{4} + i^{-4}=1+1=2$
- $S(5)=i^{5} + i^{-5}=S(1)$
- $\dots$

Answer (score 1):

> If n is even then it will become  $$\frac{2}{-1}$$

False. Actually, you need to, in this case, look at $n$ modulo $4$. This is because $i^{4k} = (-1)^4=1$, while $i^{4k+2} = i^{4k}\cdot i^2 = 1\cdot (-1) = -1$

Answer (score 0):

$i=e^{i\pi/2}$

Using [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos(\varphi) +i\sin(\varphi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi)

$$S(n)=2\cos\dfrac{n\pi}2$$

Now if $S(n)=S(n+m)$

$$2\cos\dfrac{n\pi}2=2\cos\dfrac{(m+n)\pi}2$$

$$\iff4\sin\dfrac{m\pi}4\sin\dfrac{\pi(m+2n)}4=0$$

As $\sin\dfrac{\pi(m+2n)}4$ is not constant, $$\sin\dfrac{m\pi}4=0$$

$$\implies\dfrac{m\pi}4=r\pi\iff m=4r$$
 where $r$ is an integer

So, the fundamental period of $S(n)$ is $4$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Euler identity:
$$ e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x) $$
Where for $ x = \pi/2 $ you obtain that $ i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} $. Now from the initial question you derive that:
$$ S(n) = i^n+i^{-n} = (e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^n + (e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{-n} = e^{i\frac{n\pi}{2}} + e^{-i\frac{n\pi}{2}} = $$ $$ = \cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) + i\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})+\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) - i\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) = 2\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})$$
And for $ n = 0,1,2 $ you get the desired three values $ 2,0,-2. $

Comment: Using Euler's formula for this is a bit of overkill, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but it is a neat solution in my opinion and Euler's identity is a powerful tool that is not that hard to learn.