# Showing $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =2^n(n+1)\cos^nx\cos(n+2)x$, and the counterpart for sine

Tags: trigonometry

> How do I show that
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =2^n(n+1)\cos^nx\cos(n+2)x\tag{1}$$
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\sin2kx =2^n(n+1)\cos^nx\sin(n+2)x\tag{2}$$

**My try:**

From power-reduction formula, if $n$ is odd, we have
$$\cos^{n}x = \frac{2}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n}{k}\cos(n-2k)x\tag{3}$$
Putting (3) in (1), assuming $n$ is odd in (1), we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =2^{n}(n+1)\cos(n+2)x\frac{2}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n}{k}\cos(n-2k)x$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =2(n+1)\cos(n+2)x\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n}{k}\cos(n-2k)x$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =2(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n}{k}\cos(n+2)x\cos(n-2k)x \tag{4}$$
Using the product-to-sum identity on the RHS of (4), we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =2(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\cos2(n-k+1)x+\cos2(k+1)x}{2}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\cos2kx =(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n}{k}\left(\cos2(n-k+1)x+\cos2(k+1)x\right)$$

This is where I got stuck. I am thinking if the odd part could be solved, it will pave the way for the even part. Same for (2).

> How can I proceed or is there a simpler way of solving it?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Using [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos(\varphi) +i\sin(\varphi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi)

$$C+iS$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}kk(e^{2ix})^k$$

$$=(n+1)e^{2ix}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom n{k-1}(e^{2ix})^{k-1}$$

$$=(n+1)e^{2ix}(1+e^{2ix})^n$$

as for  $k>0,k\binom{n+1}k=(n+1)\binom n{k-1}$

Now $1+e^{2ix}=e^{ix}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})=e^{ix}(2\cos x)$